# Odd Tukey Test Grouping Post Anova Analysis

Tags: grouping, mean, anova, tukey

I noticed an odd grouping in group 10 and 11. group 11 with area avg of 5470 is clustered into its own group b and group 10  is shared between group a and b but has a lower area average of 4056. Why is this the case, shouldnt the grouping be the other way around?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[Tukey Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIyUQ.jpg)

ANOVA Results
Area         Sum of Sq= 4.90x109     Mean Sq=490209868    F-statistic=3.481     pvalue= 0.000507***

I did this on R. The other parameters tested except for this one